# ATM pin verification in java

Tags: java, loops

I am very new to programming and need some help. I need to write a simple program that verifies an ATM users pin number. The program will either, accept the pin and exit, tell the user it was an incorrect pin and have them try again up to three times, or tell the user their card is locked because they were wrong three times. I have searched for over an hour now and cannot find an example of this. I know i will need to use a scanner and a loop to accomplish this but not much else. Any help is appreciated as it is due by midnight......

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Typically a question here includes what you have tried and some sample code that you have written.  If you want someone to give you code that works - you probably won't get much positive responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i = 1..3
    prompt user for pin
    read pin
    check pin
    if pin is correct, exit
    tell user they were wrong and try again

tell user they got it incorrect three times and their card is locked.
```

I will give one hint which can trip some newbies up.  The pin is an integer, right?  So you might be tempted to use `Scanner.nextInt()` to get the input--*do not* do that!  Just get the next line and compare Strings (you may have to use `String.trim()` to get rid of whitespace).  It's more complicated if you try to use `Scanner.nextInt()` (what if the user enters something that cannot be parsed as an integer).

Comment: I haven't looked at java for years - it sure has evolved a lot.

Comment: @MikeWeber This isn't Java, it's obviously pseudocode.

Comment: I thought this was pretty good for giving a direction to go without just handing the OP the code.

Comment: Yes, it does cover all the necessary functionality - I was trying to have fun with the simplicity of pseudocode, and how one day, maybe, coding will actually look like that.

Comment: @MikeWeber Oh man, you're asking a lot, lol.  You can make code look like that with object oriented programming (which I have found virtually no one knows/adheres to).  Still you need to write the methods/objects to do the nitty gritty--I don't think that will ever go away (it can within a certain niche, but not in general, I don't think).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.Console;  

public class atm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int counter = 3;
        int attempt = 3;
        char[] ch = null;
        Console c=System.console();    
        System.out.println("Enter PIN: ");    
        ch=c.readPassword();    
            String pass=String.valueOf(ch);
            if(pass.equals("enigma")){
                System.out.println("Correct PIN entered!");
            }
        while(!pass.equals("enigma") && attempt != 0){
            System.out.println("Invalid PIN entered!. " + --attempt + " attempts remaining.");  
            counter--;
            if(attempt != 0){
                c=System.console();
                System.out.println("Enter PIN: ");
                ch=c.readPassword(); 
                pass=String.valueOf(ch);
                if(pass.equals("enigma")){
                    System.out.println("Correct PIN entered!");
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("your card has locked!");
                break;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

**Note that you can put your PIN code instead of "enigma" string, I hope that will help.**

Answer (score -1):

here is the implementation of pseudo code answered by @Jared above

```
boolean cardLockFlag = false ;
String password;
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
password = "password" ;
if(!cardLockFlag){
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
   if(password.equals(scan.next().trim())){
 System.out.println("Success :) ");
 break ;

}else{
if(i==2){
cardLockFlag = true ;
}else{
System.out.println("Wrong Password");
}
}
}

}else{
System.out.println("Card is Locked");
}
```

Comment: Also, please, if you're going to put in code, at least format it nicely.